# I am looking for jquery ui tabs with cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Does anyone have a copy of **jquery ui tabs with cookie** that is found in this link?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie.

I have tried an example of it but it does not work at all. I don't know what I am missing, so if anyone has a working example, please share it with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thank you everyone for your help. I downloaded the whole bundle from http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie and I added this code in the page and it worked.
Thanks again for your quick reply.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                cookie: {
                    // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
                    expires: 1
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
    spinner: "",
    cookie: {}
  });
```

But you do need this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="/path/to/your/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```